# How to 'Open With' in downloads dock flyout

Tags: macos, mojave, dock

On the dock in Mojave I have a Downloads icon which, when clicked, displays a window type thing with a list of downloaded files.

I would like to right-click on an icon and select the app to open the file with. How can I get that context menu to display for icons in the downloads window?

Comment: At the top of the "window type thing" arranged in the shape of an arc (yeah - weird) is an icon to open the Downloads folder in Finder. If you click on that, you'll of course open a Finder window in which the right-click options are available. I know of no way to add that to "the arc" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get that context menu to display for icons in the downloads window?

You can’t.

The [stacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stacks_(Mac_OS)) were designed to be a quick way to open items in the folder.  If you wanted to do anything more (copy, move, delete, etc.), you needed to actually be in a Finder window, thus the shortcut at the top which launches you into one.